# Logistic regression in which a factor is not significant but levels of that factor are

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, categorical-data

My question pertains to logistic regression. The overall model was significant, but the main IV (study group), which has 4 levels, was not (p = 0.1098):

```
Testing Global Null Hypothesis: BETA=0
Test                   Chi-Square   DF  Pr > ChiSq
Likelihood Ratio        149.7148    9   <.0001
Score                   175.1632    9   <.0001
Wald                    167.9565    9   <.0001

Type 3 Analysis of Effects
Effect         DF   Wald Chi-Square    Pr > ChiSq
age            1        5.4728          0.0193
sex            1        0.1211          0.7279
studygrp       3        6.0372          0.1098
p1susrev       1        0.4059          0.5240
p1cons         1       78.6831          <.0001
p1majcon       1        2.8332          0.0923
p1crash        1       30.2458          <.0001
```

My issue concerns the Maximum Likelihood Estimates Table, which demonstrated that despite this variable being non-significant, 3 levels of that IV actually were significant (with the reference group not being displayed):

```
Analysis of Maximum Likelihood Estimates
Parameter   DF Estimate  Standard Error  Wald Chi-Sq  Pr > ChiSq
Intercept   1 -2.9014        0.1387      437.6924       <.0001
age         1 -0.00396       0.00169       5.4728       0.0193
sex         1  0.0179        0.0514        0.1211       0.7279
studygrp 1  1  0.2616        0.1144        5.2277       0.0222
studygrp 2  1  0.2449        0.1203        4.1423       0.0418
studygrp 3  1  0.2874        0.1187        5.8648       0.0154
```

Previously I included two interaction terms (sex by study group & age by study group), but neither proved significant. Any suggestions as to how this could be interpreted?

Answer (score 5):

When you have a categorical variable (factor), you want to test the variable as a whole.  The tests that come with your table of estimated coefficients includes tests of the individual levels of the variable against the reverence level.  That isn't what you want, and it is prone to confusion (e.g., they will change if you change the reference level).  The three indicated levels only look significant because they don't take the full picture into account and because you happen to be only comparing against the lowest group instead of a group in the middle.  When you test the variable as a whole, you see that the variability of the proportions is reasonable.  The interpretation here is that you don't have sufficient evidence to conclude that the study groups differ.